# There are too many problems with the installation "npm install nodegit"

Tags: npm

```
PS P:\CSS-Strategy> git --version
git version 2.36.1.windows.1
PS P:\CSS-Strategy> npm --version
8.13.2
PS P:\CSS-Strategy> node --version
v16.17.0
```

PS P:\CSS-Strategy> npm install nodegit

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be

problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.13.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future

npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\junu\AppData\Local\Temp\install6629975969.cmd

npm ERR! [nodegit] Running pre-install script

npm ERR! [nodegit] Running install script

npm ERR! Failed to execute 'P:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit\build\Release\nodegit.node --module_name=nodegit --module_path=P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp

npm ERR! info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info

npm ERR! using node-pre-gyp@0.13.0

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit\build\Release\nodegit.node" (not found)

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp

npm ERR! http GET https://axonodegit.s3.amazonaws.com/nodegit/nodegit/nodegit-v0.27.0-node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http

npm ERR! 404 https://axonodegit.s3.amazonaws.com/nodegit/nodegit/nodegit-v0.27.0-node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://axonodegit.s3.amazonaws.com/nodegit/nodegit/nodegit-v0.27.0-node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for nodegit@0.27.0 and node@16.17.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://axonodegit.s3.amazonaws.com/nodegit/nodegit/nodegit-v0.27.0-node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz

npm ERR! gyp

npm ERR!

npm ERR! info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! gyp

npm ERR! info using node-gyp@9.0.0

npm ERR! gyp

npm ERR! info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64

npm ERR! gyp

npm ERR! info ok

npm ERR! gyp

npm ERR! info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! gyp info

npm ERR! using node-gyp@9.0.0

npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64

npm ERR! gyp info

npm ERR! find Python using Python version 3.10.7 found at "C:\Users\junu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"

npm ERR! gyp ERR!

npm ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.8.30711.63) found at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp

npm ERR! ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.

npm ERR! gyp

npm ERR! ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp

npm ERR! ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)

npm ERR! gyp ERR!

npm ERR! stack     at C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14

npm ERR! gyp ERR!

npm ERR! stack     at C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16

npm ERR! gyp ERR!

npm ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:408:5)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043

npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "P:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit\build\Release\nodegit.node" "--module_name=nodegit" "--module_path=P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit\build\Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd

npm ERR! P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0

npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR!

npm ERR! build error

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp

npm ERR! ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'P:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\junu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit\build\Release\nodegit.node --module_name=nodegit --module_path=P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR!

npm ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR!

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "P:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd P:\CSS-Strategy\node_modules\nodegit

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - Could not finish install

npm ERR! [nodegit] ERROR - finished with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\junu\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-12T15_44_33_340Z-debug-0.log